# How to let prompt read text input & print out customised text messages?

Tags: javascript, textbox, prompt

I'm trying to do a text adventure game using basic JS. Basically, a user will have 2 options, and the prompt box should print out corresponding messages based on choices the user make.

I'm guessing that what missing is an event listener--but I'm not sure how to go about implementing that.

```js
let message = prompt("Hi this is an adventure. Select your input as A or B. In front of you there is a sign. Pick  A. Forest B. Lake")

if (A) {
  prompt("you see the bushes ahead of you rustling.You-- A.proceed ahead  B.turn back and run")
};
else if (B) {
  prompt("you see the water bubbling. You--A. walk up B.--flee")
}
```

Comment: The value the user enters into the prompt window is stored in the `message` variable as a string. You need to compare if `message` equals the string `"A"` in your if statement and the same with `"B"`.

Comment: You also do not need a `;` after your first if-block

Comment: What Nick means is you need `if (message.toUpperCase() === "A") {` to allow user to type a or A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare `if (message.toUpperCase() === "A") {` to allow user to type a or A

You will also have a lot less code if you use an object and a form

```js
const advent = {
  "Start": {
    "text": "Hi this is an adventure. Click the buttons to make your choice. In front of you there is a sign. You go direction",
    "a": "Forest",
    "b": "Lake"
  },
  "Forest": {
    "text": "you see the bushes ahead of you rustling. You --",
    "a": "proceed ahead",
    "b": "turn back and run"

  },
  "Lake": {
    "text": "you see the water bubbling. You--",
    "a": "walk up",
    "b": "flee"
  },
  "walk up": {
    "text": "You drown; The end"
  },
  "flee": {
    "text": "You fall in a hole and die; The end"
  }
};

let currentPath = advent["Start"]

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const text = document.getElementById("text");
  const A = document.getElementById("a");
  const B = document.getElementById("b");
  const show = () => {
    text.innerHTML = currentPath.text; console.log(currentPath.a)
    if(currentPath.a) A.value = currentPath.a
    if(currentPath.b) B.value = currentPath.b
  };

  const form = document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    currentPath = advent[currentPath[tgt.id]]
    document.getElementById("choices").hidden = (!currentPath.a && !currentPath.b); // hide if no choices
    show()
  });
  show(); // start
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <div id="text"></div>
  <div id="choices"><input type="button" id="a" value="A"> <input type="button" id="b" value="B"></div>
</form>
```